# IPhone, Android - how to make one app on install complete, install second app?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store-connect

I have an app in iTune and Android. iTune on every updates take weeks to release my app and its pointless to renew the app in iTune and Android store.

For new feature i made a second app for iTune and Android store. Is there any option when someone install this new app or my old app. That automatically after installation is completed it checks for dependencies and complete the other app too?

Does anything exist already for iTune and Android store?

**EDIT:**

[Like in desktop world](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/20868/net-framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-installer-for-innosetup)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That automatically after installation is completed it checks for dependencies and complete the other app too?

No. You must do your checks yourself and suggest installing missing apps.

Comment: No. There's no concept of dependencies of that type you are talking about in neither store.

Comment: Exactly. Automatic dependencies like that we talk about would be perfect vector to infect multiple devices with malicious software. It'd just be sufficient to attack the popular dependency  and wait :)

Comment: OK - i need some kind of dependencies check/install like my EDIT.

Comment: Well the dependencies that i want to install is just an second app in the store (Which was validated by the Store managers, so its less risky cause the dependencies app was already validated by store inspectors)

Comment: That's should not be problematic. PackageManager on android will give you list of installed packages so just look for ids of what you require and complain if missing. Not sure about iOS now as it was ages I last time lurked into their SDK, this is beyond the scope of this question ;)